# How to deny all stored procedures to specific user in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I already have numerous existing stored procedure in database. I am now re-creating users and giving them access to tables, schemas and stored procedures.

How can I deny access to all of my stored procedures without denying it one by one in securables properties of user?

Comment: They don't have permission to them by default, unless you also gave them other overriding role. So just don't grant them execute permission to begin with

Comment: I suppose you could create a *"`db_denyexecutor`"* role; would just be `DENY` instead of `GRANT`: [db_executor](https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Adding%20a%20db_executor%20role.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Datareader and datawriter don't grant execute on stored procedures.
So you can grant either/both of these and then grant the required stored proc execute permissions required.